# HTMl5/CSS3 Frameworks to use that will work with windows8 phone and window8 tablet as well as ipad and web browsers?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I am thinking of using Bootstrap (HTML5/CSS3) for the web and mobile development since its also supports responsive web design and works with mobile. Will bootstrap work with window 8 tablet and windows phone? Or is there any other framework(s) I can use that will work well with window 8 tablet as well as for web and iOS?

Is it possible to develop the UI for windows8 tablet and windows 8 phone using bootstrap?

Could anyone recommend me some frameworks and their compatibility with web, iPad and windows 8 tablet/windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Try Zurb's Foundation 4 or 5 for windows phone compatibility. It loads on my Windows 8 test phone, and doesn't bug out on responsive queries.

[Vermillion Comparison of Responsive Frameworks](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php)

Alternatively use any framework and put in the fixes for windows phone.

[Matt Stow's Blog on Windows 8 Bug](http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html)